# Manipulating var from father in child process

Tags: c, process

Can someone pls explain why the output of the following program is 1 and not 2?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int x = 1;
int *y = &x; 

pid_t pid = fork();

if (pid == 0) {
    *y = 2;
    exit(0);
} else {
    wait(NULL);
    printf("father: %d\n", x); 
}   

return 1;
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect the pid to be 0? If fork() didn't fail then it'll contain the pid of the child process...

Comment: and the child process gets 0...

Comment: ...in another address space (the pointer address you see is _virtual_).

Comment: Correct! But why is the address of x the same in the parent and in the child? Are the addresses relative to the address space of the process? // EDIT: Got it! (virtual) THX!

Answer (score 3):

`fork` doesn't create a thread, it creates a whole new process.

The address space of the child is a copy of the parent's one, they don't share it.

Modifications done by the parent are not visible from the child, and vice-versa, unless the specifically set something up to do so (via shared memory segments for instance).

Comment: Thats what i thought too but if I print the memory address in x it is the same in the parent and child

Comment: You shall use "%p" to print the value of a pointer. "%d" most propably swallows away significant bits of the address you want to display, also it interprets the value as signed, which does not make much sense for a pointer @pluckyDuck

Comment: @pluckyDuck: that's expected. (But you should indeed use `%p`.) What you see when you do that is a _virtual_ address. Since the address space is copied, virtual addresses are initially identical in both processes. (And they can in fact map to the same physical address as long as neither process does writes if the OS does copy-on-write optimizations.)

Comment: @Mat does the OS a copy-on-write optimization for fork? Impressive!!! (even if I can't imagine many tasks where the process doesn't write anything)

Comment: @Adriano: yes, Linux does and I'm pretty sure most modern Unix-like kernels to - it is a really important optimization for the (very common) `fork`/`exec` case: you really don't want to copy the whole parent's address space (which could be huge) just to throw it away completely on the next syscall.

Comment: Tnx @Mat, I mostly work on Windows. I would +10 just for this pearl!